# How can I create a modified Base64 encoded UUID in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am interested in creating a modified encoded UUID but I am having a heck of a time getting the right format. What I currently have does not compile for reasons unknown but oddly Im able to run it in a playground. Here is the function:

```
class func genID() -> String {
  let uuid = NSUUID.UUID()
  let data = NSData(bytes:&uuid, length:16)
  let base64 = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
  let options = NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch
  let result = base64
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/", withString: "-", options: options, range: nil)
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "_", options: options, range: nil)
    .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("=", withString: "", options: options, range: nil)
  return result
}
```

The problem is flagged on the second line of the function; the creation of the data value. Strangely that line does work in a playground. Any help would be appreciated. So what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that shouldn't work anyways I fear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `NSData` object from `NSUUID` with

```
let uuid = NSUUID.UUID()
// data object with appropriate size:
let data = NSMutableData(length: 16)
// fill the bytes from the UUID:
uuid.getUUIDBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer(data.mutableBytes))
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this without using NSUUID by converting the uuid_t type to a Data object.  This type is an alias for a 16-byte tuple.  Looks a little strange in the implementation, but it works, and this is fairly future proof if for some reason the uuid_t type changes.  Here's the UUID extension I created:

```
import Foundation

extension UUID {
    var base64String: String {
        return self.data.base64EncodedString()
    }

    var data: Data {
        var result = Data()
        let uuidTuple = self.uuid
        // NOTE: There are clever ways to iterate over a tuple in Swift,
        // but I actually want this to not compile if the implementation of uuid_t
        // changes in the future
        result.append(uuidTuple.0)
        result.append(uuidTuple.1)
        result.append(uuidTuple.2)
        result.append(uuidTuple.3)
        result.append(uuidTuple.4)
        result.append(uuidTuple.5)
        result.append(uuidTuple.6)
        result.append(uuidTuple.7)
        result.append(uuidTuple.8)
        result.append(uuidTuple.9)
        result.append(uuidTuple.10)
        result.append(uuidTuple.11)
        result.append(uuidTuple.12)
        result.append(uuidTuple.13)
        result.append(uuidTuple.14)
        result.append(uuidTuple.15)
        return result
    }
}
```